# How does read_csv read a csv UTF-8 file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, read-csv

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCx4Y.png) How to rectify this error.
I want to read the data in excel correctly and print as a dataframe.
The raw data was copied from UCL repository into an excel file and saved in csv utf-8 format.
when i read it that gets displayed and the column names are getting shifted and Nan values get displayed

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Setting columns names inside `read_csv` is not required. They may be adjusted after import if needed. What is the output if you don't set column names? But first, please adapt your question following the above comment. Also [mre] and [tour] would help.

Answer (score 0):

while reading `csv` using pandas, use `encoding='utf-8'`

```
df = pd.read_csv('autompg1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

*Note: Try to post the code in the question rather than as a link to image*

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I did try that but it didnt change. The problem is the data gets displayed but the column headings move to one side and the contents get displayed as Nan